# PHP If Else Alternative syntax for control structures

Tags: php

I am using this syntax but I also need to add an else statement for the event that `fl_postponed = true`:

```
<?php if (strval(get_field('fl_postponed')) == false) : ?> 
<?php get_custom_date(); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Not sure what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php…?

Comment: use <?php else: ?> else stuff <?php endif; ?>

Comment: ok thank you, this is what I was looking for alternative syntax structures

Comment: The manual at the link above doesn't mention <?php else: ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use multi line PHP syntax. Your code above could be replicated with equal functionality by just expanding the PHP tags:

```
<?php 
if (strval(get_field('fl_postponed')) == false) {
    get_custom_date();
}
?>
```

Then you could add in the `else` statement:

```
<?php 
if (strval(get_field('fl_postponed')) == false) {
    get_custom_date();
} else {
    // More code here
}
?>
```